# Ubuntu 16.04 Crashing

Tags: freeze, crash, lockup

I recently switched from Windows 10 to Ubuntu and at least twice a day it crashes and I have to hold down the power button. I know it's not my computer's hardware that's causing it. System temperatures are stable. I haven't changed any settings so far.

Comment: Please provide some useful information. A good starting point would be to look for any unusual messages in the logfiles. For example, you could check the file "/var/log/kern.log" after you experienced a crash. See here for more information on log files: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LinuxLogFiles